# How do I disable validator once validation is complete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validator in a registration form.  I want to encrypt the password before sending it to the server.  Both the password and confirm password need to be encrypted and this causes the validator to crash with "too many calls to stack" error in the console, presumably because the onchange method is firing when I update the values in the form before submit...

```
        $.validator.setDefaults( {
          submitHandler: function(e) {
              $("#signupForm").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
              });

              var hp = $('#password').val();
              var hc = $('#passwordConfirm').val();
              var hb = $('#heartbeat').val();

              hp = CryptoJS.SHA384(hp);
              hp = CryptoJS.SHA384(hp + hb);
              hc = CryptoJS.SHA384(hc);
              hc = CryptoJS.SHA384(hc + hb);
              $('#password').val(hp);
              $('#passwordConfirm').val(hc);
              $('#signupForm').submit();
            }
        } );
```

How do I disable the validator at the start of the submitHandler function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"too many calls to stack" error in the console, presumably because the onchange method is firing when I update the values in the form before submit*

Um no.  There is no validation being triggered inside the `submitHandler` since the form is *already deemed valid* at this point.  Validation is *only* triggered through user interaction with the form.  Programmatically changing form values cannot trigger validation unless you also programmatically trigger validation.

> *How do I disable the validator at the start of the submitHandler function?*

You don't.  You do not need to disable validation at the start of the `submitHandler` because validation is 100% complete at this point.  No additional validation is triggered by the `submitHandler`.

Let's break it down...

```
submitHandler: function(e) {
    $("#signupForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    // your encryption code here
    $('#signupForm').submit();
}
```

1. You cannot pass `e` into the `submitHandler` and expect the plugin to accept that as representing an "event".  There are no events in this context.  `form` is the only argument accepted and it represents the form object recognized by the plugin.

   ```
   submitHandler: function(form) {
   ```
2. `e.preventDefault()` makes absolutely no sense inside the `submitHandler` callback and is probably doing nothing in here.  Also see item 1.  The `submitHandler` callback function is already preventing the default behavior of the submit action.
3. `$("#signupForm").submit` is causing your loop...  form is valid so `submitHandler` fires, where you tell it to submit again causing `submitHandler` to be fired again.... etc. etc.
4. The last line, `$('#signupForm').submit()`, should be `form.submit()`.

See [this section of the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-too-much-recursion), which specifically addresses the recursion loop you've created.

In other words...

- the jQuery Validate plugin is preventing the default submit through its own `submitHandler` function.
- then you would prevent the default submit handler routine of the jQuery Validate plugin by replacing it with your own custom `submitHandler` function.

Resume normal plugin flow by calling `form.submit()` at the end of the `submitHandler` function.  (Optionally, `form.submit` can be replaced here with an Ajax submission.)

The whole thing should be as simple as this...

```
submitHandler: function(form) { // <- note the "form" argument
    // below replaces default submitHandler callback
    // form is valid here - no validation is triggered
    // your encryption code here
    form.submit(); // now submit data (does not call submitHandler or new validation)
}
```